# Re-engineering to create UML Diagrams from .NET binary assembly

Tags: .net, c#

What is the base way to generate UML diagrams (both class and sequence) from .NET assembly using OpenSource tools?

The [200% Reflective Class Diagram Creation Tool](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207280/200-Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool) cannot be used due on problems [starting custom build on machine](https://glot.io/snippets/f6xp8xpf03).

Ready-to use builds needed.

Comment: All Reflector addins [are not up-to-date](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=reflectoraddins)

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. You may edit your own question if you have further information to add. Comments are intentionally volatile and may disappear in the future without notice.